# Induced Matrix Norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

I have trouble following a proof of the induced Norm $||\cdot||_1$

The proof can be found here: http://nptel.ac.in/courses/Webcourse-contents/IIT-KANPUR/Numerical%20Analysis/numerical-analysis/kadalbajoo/lec1/fnode3.html

I'm at the step where we defined $$C=\max_{1\le j\le n}{ \sum^n_{i=1}|a_{ij}|}$$ which ist $||A||_1$.

They conclude $||A||_1 \le C$

And "to show this is an equality, we demonstrate an x for wich ${||Ax||_1 \over||x||_1} = C$ "

My Question is, how does finding an x shows this is an equality?

Comment: Well if you find such an $x$ you know that $\|A\|_1 \geq C$ and $\|A\|_1 \leq C$.

Comment: How, I don't see it.

Comment: Because $\|A\|_1 = \sup_{x\in B_1(0)\setminus\{0\}}  \frac{\|Ax\|_1}{\|x\|_1} \geq \frac{\|Ax\|_1}{\|x\|_1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I get your question correctly, but it seems like the induced norm is defined in the usual way, i.e.
$$
\|A\|_1:=\sup_{x\ne 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_1}{\|x\|_1}
$$
and the goal is to show that
$$
C:=\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant n}\sum_{i=1}^n
\left|a_{ij}\right|=\sup_{x\ne 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_1}{\|x\|_1}$$
The inequality $\|A\|_1\leqslant C$ says essentially that for every $x$ you have
$$
\frac{\|Ax\|_1}{\|x\|_1}\leqslant C
$$ But you don't know yet if the $\sup$ is a $\max$. So if there exists an $x\ne 0$ such that $C=\frac{\|Ax\|_1}{\|x\|_1}$ , you're done.